# Order Dictionary<string,object> rows that fills DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, datagridview

I've making a winforms app to create invoices. I have a dataGridView(DGV) and I fill it with a dictionary. The problem is that I need to order manually (not alphabetically) the rows, because the user decides where to put the concept of the invoice. The problem is how to order dictionary items in order to refill the DGV ordered.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty vague.  The question seems to be how do I sort a collection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting should normally be done by the control IF the control you are using supports custom sorting.  It appears that the control you are using does support custom sorting.

See `SortCompare` event from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx)

sample:

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender,
    DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    // Try to sort based on the cells in the current column.
    e.SortResult = System.String.Compare(
        e.CellValue1.ToString(), e.CellValue2.ToString());

    // If the cells are equal, sort based on the ID column.
    if (e.SortResult == 0 && e.Column.Name != "ID")
    {
        e.SortResult = System.String.Compare(
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex1].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString(),
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex2].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is I've looking for. I'll try and say something. By the way, now I'm thinking that I'll need to store order in database. But it's an other problem.

Comment: @uoah - sure, feel free to mark this as the answer.  As for storing it in the database you may need to add another column to the database table that holds an integer that indicates the position/order (1,2,3,4).

Comment: Yes I know that I hav eto add another column for storing the order but I don't know how to change the position/order when changing the order. Don't worry about marking as answer, when I test it and works I mark, thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for OrderedDictionary?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Comment: I don't know about it. With orderedDictionary, I can order manually the items?